# Inserting text before a titlerule in titlesec

Tags: titlesec

I'm using `titlesec` to replicate the header of a CV I made in Microsoft Word. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, left=1.27cm, bottom=0.5cm, right=1.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ulem}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}
\newfontfamily\subsectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}

\titleformat{\section}{\filcenter\sectionfont\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont}{\thesection}{0em}{}[{\titlerule[1.4pt]}]
\titleformat{\subsection}{\subsectionfont\selectfont}{\thesection}{0em}{\uline}



\begin{document}
\section*{David Krappenschitz}
\subsection*{Education}

\end{document}
```

Which, I am happy to say, generates the following header:

[image]

I would like to now (still using `titlesec`) achieve something like this:

[image]

How can I go about doing this?

## EDIT

As @campa indicated there might be no real reason to stick with titlesec here. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, left=1.27cm, bottom=0.5cm, right=1.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ulem}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}
\newfontfamily\subsectionfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}

\titleformat{\section}{\filcenter\sectionfont\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont}{\thesection}{0em}{}%[{\titlerule[1.4pt]}]
\titleformat{\subsection}{\subsectionfont\selectfont}{\thesection}{0em}{\uline}



\begin{document}
  \section*{David Krappenschitz}

  26 College Ave \textbullet College City, FL \textbullet +001-865-8976 \textbullet dave.krappenschitz@gmail.com

  \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

  \subsection*{Education}

\end{document}
```

But for some reason the `rule` and text itself are not properly aligned with the titles anymore...

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason for using `titlesec` at all?

Comment: I guess not... I also tried without... Please see edit to original question...

Comment: The package that eases customisation of headings is `titiling`.

Comment: Your comment is right. I corrected the answer. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fancyhdr`. It will put the heading that you define on each page. (The rule comes free).

[image: c]
.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm, headsep=1.5cm, left=1.27cm, bottom=0.5cm, right=1.27cm]{geometry}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\headerfont{Copperplate Gothic Bold}  

\usepackage{fancyhdr}% added
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
    {\headerfont{\Large\bfseries David Krappenschitz} \medskip\\
        {\normalfont\small\itshape 26 College Ave \textbullet\ College City, FL \textbullet\ 0123-456\,789 \textbullet\ dave.krappenschitz@somemail.com\medskip}
}} % added

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
    
\section*{EDUCATION}
    
\kant[1-21] 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a lot closer to what I'm looking for. Is it strictly necessary to use `\parbox` and `\centering`? Doesn't `fancyhdr` automatically center the header contents when you specify the `[C]` option?